# Java: How do I return the object properly?

Tags: java

Ok, so I have been working on a school project for a while, and I am trying to count up mutual interests of different users. So, I am trying to store the "points" they get in a HashMap for each mutual interest they have, and then choose the user with the most mutual interests(highest HashMap key). I have the comparison of the integers done, but how do I return the User with the most points?

Example TXT file it reads from and loads into List:

Daniel: adcbadcbd

Jimmy: abdcbdcab

```
        public User getMutualUser(User user) {
    final Map<User, Integer> points = new HashMap<User, Integer>();
    for(User u : users) {
        if(u.getName().equals(user.getName())) continue;
        for(int i = 0; i < u.getAnswers().size(); i++) {
            if(u.getAnswers().get(i).equals(user.getAnswers().get(i))) {
                System.out.println(u.getName() + " - " + u.getAnswers().get(i));
                int current = points.get(u);
                points.put(u, current + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
        public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
            Integer score1 = points.get(u1);
            Integer score2 = points.get(u2);
            return score1.compareTo(score2);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Map` can only have 1 value per key, which means if more than one `User` gets the same number of points (ie. `score1.equals(score2)`) you will lose data (one of the Users) from the `Map`.

Additionally, you may have the same `User` more than once, if they have been entered into the `Map` twice as their points get incremented.

Finally, for a `Map` it is a bad idea to use as a key a value which will end up changing. The whole point of a key is that it is constant for a given value.

I recommend swapping the key and values around in your `Map`, and in fact, just use a `HashMap` (or a Guava `Multiset`) and keep a separate `List` of `User`s and run a `Collections.sort()` using a `Comparator` which uses the `Map` as a lookup. (The `Map` would have to be `final`.)

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
final Map<User, Integer> points = new HashMap<User, Integer>(); // assumes User has hashcode() / equals() defined
for(User u : users) {
    // populate the points Map
}
Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
    public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
        Integer score1 = points.get(u1);
        Integer score2 = points.get(u2);
        return score1.compareTo(score2);
    }
});
```

Finally, return your highest scoring `User` with `users.get(0)`.

Note: if `users.get(0)` turns out to be the lowest scoring user, just swap `score1.compareTo(score2)` for `score2.compareTo(score1)` in the `Comparator`.

Comment: You should probably clarify the language in your opening paragraph.  Saying a `Map` can only have "1 key per value" is a backwards.  A map can have only "1 VALUE per KEY".  You should also point out that as far as a `Map` is concerned if `score1.equals(score2)` the key is the same.

Comment: Thanks so much, but how should I return a User at the end?

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the answer based upon both these comments.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good - you just need to return the last user in the list!

Add this line at the end of your method:

```
return users.get(users.size() - 1);
```

---

It can be easier to sort in the opposite direction then return the *first* element:

In the comparator, reverse to order:

```
return score2.compareTo(score1);
```

Then

```
return users.get0);
```